# Can WSGI middleware run code after a response is returned?

Tags: python, wsgi, wheezy-web

I understand that WSGI Middleware's purpose is to extend functionality between a request and a response.

But can some of this code be run after the response is returned?

I need to store a request/response log in an external database, and wouldn't want this to slow the response times down.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you useing django? If so, you should add this as a tag.

Comment: @Konstantin using Wheezy Web :)

Comment: I didn't know about that. Does my answer still apply? Or should I modify it so you can accept it?

Comment: @Konstantin yes it does! Totally forgot about using a queue, although running some code after the HTTP response is returned would potentially be less time consuming. Thanks for sharing, I'm happy to tick your answer if I don't get a reply targeted to Wheezy :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider spawning a new thread or using a queue manager?

This way you can return the view and process the data in the background.

This answer here has more information:

[How to fork a process in python/django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155487/how-to-fork-a-process-in-python-django)